# gernerating BlurDataUrl to use in Nextjs is not working in production

Tags: next.js, placeholder, blur, nextjs-image

I try to call function that will generate blurDataUrl on client-side based on this [blog](https://ironeko.com/posts/how-to-blurred-images-on-load-in-next-js)

```
/page/index.js
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCardData = async () => {
      const cardData = await axios.get("/api/blueDataUrl");
      setCardData(() => cardData.data.blurData);
    };
    fetchCardData();
  }, []);
```

```
/api/blueDataUrl

import { returnProps } from "../../utils/imageMetadata";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  // Get your data from a database or any other source
  const cardData = [
    {
      title: "No login required for student",
      picture:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/tatugacamp.com/Avatar%20students/IMG_3064.PNG",
      description: " Students can submit their homework without logging in.",
    },
    {
      title: "Gamification in classroom",
      picture:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/tatugacamp.com/Avatar%20students/IMG_3060.PNG",
      description:
        "Our platform incorporates gamification to make teaching a fantastic experience.",
    },
    {
      title: "Export your data to Excel",
      picture:
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/tatugacamp.com/Avatar%20students/IMG_3062.PNG",
      description:
        "With our platform, you can easily export your data to Excel",
    },
  ];

  const blurData = await Promise.all(
    cardData.map(async (item) => {
      const imageProps = await returnProps(item.picture);
      return { ...item, imageProps };
    })
  );

  res.status(200).json({
    blurData,
  });
}
```

and here is the custom utils that handle generating blurDataUrl

```
ulits/imageMetadata.js

import { getPlaiceholder } from "plaiceholder";
import visit from "unist-util-visit";


// Just to check if the node is an image node
function isImageNode(node) {
  const img = node;
  return (
    img.type === "element" &&
    img.tagName === "img" &&
    img.properties &&
    typeof img.properties.src === "string"
  );
}

// Returns the props of given `src` to use for blurred images
export async function returnProps(src) {
  // Calculate image resolution (width, height)
  const res = { width: 500, height: 500 };
  // Calculate base64 for the blur
  const { base64: blurDataURL, img } = await getPlaiceholder(src);

  // If an error happened calculating the resolution, throw an error
  if (!res) throw Error(`Invalid image with src "${node.properties.src}"`);

  const { width, height } = res;

  return {
    ...img,
    width,
    height,
    blurDataURL,
  };
}

async function addProps(node) {
  // return the new props we'll need for our image
  const { width, height, blurDataURL } = await returnProps(node.properties.src);

  // add the props in the properties object of the node
  // the properties object later gets transformed as props
  node.properties.width = width;
  node.properties.height = height;

  node.properties.blurDataURL = blurDataURL;
  node.properties.placeholder = "blur";
}

const imageMetadata = () => {
  return async function transformer(tree) {
    // Create an array to hold all of the images from the markdown file
    const images = [];

    visit(tree, "element", (node) => {
      // Visit every node in the tree, check if it's an image and push it in the images array
      if (isImageNode(node)) {
        images.push(node);
      }
    });

    for (const image of images) {
      // Loop through all of the images and add their props
      await addProps(image);
    }

    return tree;
  };
};

export default imageMetadata;
```

It work completely fine in development
But when I deploy to production, it throw error status 500 Internal Server Error

So I have tried to change from client-side to getStaticProps and it works fine it both development and production. Somehow, I really need it to be called from client-side is there anyways around to do that?